# Array search PHP mysql PDO

Tags: php, arrays, pdo

Using array search for skip duplicate data from inserting. But it throws PDO error:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry
>   '053fb04a34907637530dcb86b9f121f5fe499821' for key 'id'"

```
$check=$this->pdo->prepare("select id from user_places");
$check->execute();
$a = $check->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0);

for ($i = 0; $i < count($output->results); $i++) {
    if (array_search($data[$i]['id'], $a) == "") {
        $query->bindparam(1,$data[$i]['id']);
        $query->bindparam(2,$data[$i]['name']);
        $query->bindparam(3,$data[$i]['lat']);
        $query->bindparam(4,$data[$i]['lng']);
        $query->bindparam(5,$data[$i]['place_id']);
        $query->bindparam(6,$data[$i]['types']);
        $query->bindparam(7,$data[$i]['vicinity']);
        $query->execute();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[From the manual for `array_search`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php):

> Warning
>   This function may return Boolean FALSE, but may also return a non-Boolean value which evaluates to FALSE. Please read the section on Booleans for more information. Use the === operator for testing the return value of this function.

You're checking `array_search($data[$i]['id'], $a) == ""`, which will evaluate true if `$data[$i]['id']` is found at index 0 (i.e. the first element in the array)

Try using this instead:

```
if (array_search($data[$i]['id'], $a) === false) {
```